# Maven release bug fix versioning

Tags: maven-2, version, version-control, release

I'm getting ready to deploy the first release of our software, version 1.0. Once it's out to our customer, inevitably, some bugs will be found. When I fix those bugs though, I'm not sure what "best practice" is for versioning it. When I release the fixes, would that be an entirely new version (in maven), such as 1.01 (or whatever the increment is, 1.1 for example)? Or would it still be 1.0 with some sort of classifier (maybe a date tag)?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [surprisingly thorough discussion of software versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning). It covers all the major points and discusses most of the approaches I've seen.

(In your specific case I'd go with 1.0.1 which would generally be regarded as "an update to 1.0 with no significant feature additions")

Comment: +1 for 1.0.1. A simple rule is X.Y.Z for bug fixes and X.Y for new features. And Maven offers all what you need to maintain coherent version numbers in your project without pain !

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the number in order for maven clients to recognize a newer version in the repository. The change is up to you.  I'm sure there's a best practice document somewhere but my company dictates the numbers we use so I've never looked for one.